# Why IntelPin tool build gets linker error when using wincrypt functions?

Tags: c++, windows, intel, instrumentation

I am using:

- Intel pin 3.27
- Visual Studio 2022 to compile tool
- OS Windows 10

wincrypt is defined like this:

```
namespace WINDOWS {
#include <windows.h>
#include <Wincrypt.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <LM.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
}
```

When using wincrypt.h i can access data types WINDOWS::HCRYPTKEY hKey works completely fine.
But when trying to call a function WINDOWS::CryptGetProvParam(...) or any other function i get these errors during the build:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptGetProvParam@20 referenced in function "void __cdecl argument_logger::CertOpenStore_args(class std::basic_string<char,class std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,class std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,class std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,char const *,unsigned long,unsigned long,unsigned long,void *,void *)" (?CertOpenStore_args@argument_logger@@YAXV?$basic_string@DV?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@00PBDKKKPAX2@Z)  MyPinTool   D:\pin\source\tools\MyPinTool\argument_logger.obj   1
```

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  MyPinTool   D:\pin\source\tools\MyPinTool\Release\MyPinTool.dll 1
```

##### Build works only when trying to build in Debug x64 but fails for x86 and for any Release configuration. I need tool to be built in Release and both x64 and x86.

I tried using #pragma and linking against Advapi32.lib directly but those didn't help.

Comment: You cannot put the entirety of the Windows API behind a namespace. The libraries for you to link against do not contain that namespace. This will never work. Drop the namespace.

Comment: I can't do that because bunch of things are redefined by both windows.h and pin.h, so i get errors like BOOL is ambiguous but inside the Windows API header files.

Comment: Wow. The Intel documentation is [completely unforgiving](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/98749/Pin/doc/html/index.html#namespace) about this. I would say "open a support case" or "raise a bug" but they don't offer support. I guess your only option is to isolate the windows-using bits to a separate .cpp file that _does not_ include pin.h